# Scrapy-Splash stop responding for some links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

Hi all I am working on scraping project where I am scraping an angular website. For this task I am using scrapy and splash. Before few days scraper was running perfectly fine but now for some links it is not working. It open user's timeline but not able to open video page for all users (which was work fine before this). I am not getting any error but **splash become unresponsive when request for user's video page**. I am giving sufficient time delay which is around 72000 sec.
version using
Splash 3.4: latest docker image
scrapy 1.7.3
python 3

***Edited***
Hi all, today i observe more on my splash hang problem and I think website has written some JavaScript code to detect is it a request from proper browser or from splash. Because when i open link('https://www.example.com/@user/video/6767235575733947649') in browser it works fine but when opening in splash browser with default header it redirects me to 'https://s16.examplecdn.com/example/falcon/_next/static/1.0.1.309/pages/_error.js' and after that splash get hang and throw continue sly 2019-12-11 07:33:43.712428 [render] JsConsole(https://s16.examplecdn.com/example/falcon/_next/static/chunks/commons.787eed06a7e37b82e3d0.js:1): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'h.$languageList')
So, i think this can help you guys to improve splash and hope you can help me how to figure it out.

Comment: also for some time i get this error where it totaly hang '2019-12-11 07:15:55.628458 [render] JsConsole(s16.example.com/example/falcon/_next/static/chunks/…): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'h.$languageList') '

Answer (score 0):

Splash may simply not render / not work for your webpage.

However, there are a few things you can try:

- do periodic garbage collections. Splash has this [`/_gc` endpoint](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gc) which you can "curl" periodically to free up resources
- check [`/_debug` endpoint](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#debug) info before and after you try to render that page
- check if any of the troubleshooting steps listed here help:

  - [Website is not rendered correctly](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly)
  - [Splash crashes](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#splash-crashes)

---

You may generally have better luck, less problems with a full-fledged browser controlled by [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: HI alecxe thanks for replay i have gone through your suggestions and apply some debug method and when i run splash docker image with '-v2' it stuck at last with this response '2019-12-11 06:43:00.399634 [network-manager] Finished downloading https://s16.example.com/example/falcon/_next/static/1.0.1.296/pages/_error.js'. how can i solve this. also in selenium it was not opening so move to splash.

Answer (score 0):

Here splash stop responding because it gets error.js page in response and splash hang while rendering it. so after debug and read documentation. I wrote lua script to escape hang splash from it.

```
splash:on_request(function(request)
    if string.match(request.url,'error.js') then
       print("## get error while page rendering ###")
       request.abort()
    end
end)
```